# Remove These Line Breaks with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, json, jsonp

For the life of me I can't figure out how to remove this weird formatting. This is what is getting sent to me after a `JSON.stringify(someObj)`: http://jsbin.com/ohoto5/2/edit

Click preview and you'll see the formatting. I need that to be one line so that it can go in a JSONP response ( i.e. `jsonp12345(...)` ). If it's multiple lines it will trigger a syntax error. I've tried every regex combo i can think of and nothing removes the lines. No `/[\r\n\s\t]/gi` even. The only thing that seems to remove it is: `/[\w\n]/gi` however, the issue is that i lose all the words!

Any help? Please no jQuery fixes... I'm in need of pure JavaScript.

Here is the object in Chrome (pic):
[image]

Comment: how do you get the data? do you use php? or simply an ajax call

Comment: The data will be sent via a POST request from an iframe after calling a JSON.stringify() on an object

Comment: Oh, and PHP stores the data in MySQL, so I guess if there is a fix in PHP, that'd work also

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.stringify(someObj).charCodeAt(index_of_weird_line_break)` to see what character it is? It could be some bizarre Unicode thing, if a regex for all whitespace isn't matching it.

Comment: show us the object that you are stringifying

Comment: @Lbu and @DavidJCobb look at my updated answer... it looks like a weird "↵" character?

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me that this should do it:

```
s.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '')
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/axL7H/)

Seems like every unnecessary line-break is removed.

Comment: I clicked "run" but this is what I see: https://skitch.com/oscargodson/fy4u7/edit-this-fiddle-jsfiddle-online-editor-for-the-web-javascript-mootools-jquery-prototype-yui-glow-and-dojo-html-css  --- in other words, it seems like the lines are still there

Comment: @Oscar But aren't those lines an important part of the content itself?

Comment: Stuff inside the <p>'s and <address>'s that have \n or \r will be converted to <br>s. For the line-breaks surrounding the HTML, I need to remove them or it'll throw a syntax error.

Comment: I made a few adjustments. Actually there are NO line-breaks there, they were just there because of the HTML (`<p>` is `display: block;`). Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/axL7H/1/

Comment: But the code above in my JSBin link is directly copied from my MySQL DB so there wouldn't be any styles on it and that HTML inside of the JSON never hits the DOM.

Comment: Like this: https://skitch.com/oscargodson/fyh4r/www.batchgeo.com-localhost-batchg5-api-cache-test-phpmyadmin-3.3.2deb1

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to tell what is needed, however there are many differences between what browsers recognise as whitespace, consider setting precisely what characters you wish to match, e.g.

```
// List of characters matched as white space 
var whiteSpace = '\u0009\u000a\u000b\u000c\u000d\u0020\u00a0' + 
                 '\u1680\u180e\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004' + 
                 '\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u200b' + 
                 '\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f\u3000'; 
var re = new RegExp('[' + whiteSpace + ']+', 'g');

var x = 'lots and  lots     of    space     ';

alert(x.replace(re, ' ').replace(/ +/,' '));
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe im doing it wrong? this doesn't seem to work :\ http://jsbin.com/ohoto5/4/edit

Answer (score 1):

After giving up on JS regex I tried PHP and got it first try:

```
preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $referrer['cache'])
```

where the cache is the JSON in my original JSBin link above. Now it returns:

```
callback([{"LatLng":{"Ba":45.531124,"Ca":-122.68374699999998},"InfoWindow":" <address>1125 NW 12th Ave, Portland, OR</address> <p>My first apartment</p> ","originalAddress":"1125 NW 12th Ave, Portland, OR"},{"LatLng":{"Ba":45.5138621,"Ca":-122.67767300000003},"InfoWindow":" <address>1330 SW 3rd Ave, Portland, OR</address> <p>My 2nd apartment</p> ","originalAddress":"1330 SW 3rd Ave, Portland, OR"},{"LatLng":{"Ba":45.748955,"Ca":-122.47959000000003},"InfoWindow":" <address>17501 NE 188th Ct, Brush Prairie, WA</address> <p>The first place I lived by my own</p> ","originalAddress":"17501 NE 188th Ct, Brush Prairie, WA"},{"LatLng":{"Ba":45.756944,"Ca":-122.43575800000002},"InfoWindow":" <address>18607 NE Erickson Rd, Brush Prairie, WA</address> <p>Last place I lived with my parents</p> ","originalAddress":"18607 NE Erickson Rd, Brush Prairie, WA"}])
```

Funny how the exact same regex in JS doesn't give the same result -_-

Answer (score 0):

CRLF is encoded as \r\n, so

`str = str.replace(/(\r\n)/g, '');`

should do the job.

Comment: Actually, this will only replace Windows-style line breaks. Use `str.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '');` to replace all of them (square brackets instead of parentheses).